# Arm64 Visual Studio Code, Windows 11 Arm, Parallels, MacBook Air M2

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio-code, apple-silicon

I have found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-on-arm-devices?view=vs-2022) which says "Visual Studio can run on ARM-powered devices via x86 emulation, though some features are not currently supported on ARM. As such, we don't recommend running Visual Studio on devices that use ARM-based processors, and instead recommend remotely targeted ARM devices."
But it doesn't explain WHAT doesn't work, which is pretty useless. And then, just a bit further down it says "There is a single installer for both Visual Studio x64 and Arm64 architectures."

So, is the former ONLY about Arm32, and I can get native Arm64 with full functionality by way of Windows 11 Arm on Parallels on a MacBook Air? Arm32 isn't even a thing in the Apple world, so not worried about that, but curious what I would be missing, that Microsoft can't be bothered to document in an easily found way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running VSCode on my M1 Mac, the app package contains a native arm64 binary and I've not found anything that doesn't work so far.

It could be that some extensions use native binaries and don't have arm64 versions, but I haven't found any yet.